# Show only single marker in case of overlaps in Google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a scenario where the map actually contains close to 2000 markers. However, I want to display them such that, when there is any overlap with the markers, randomly choose one of the markers and show only that and hide the others. On zooming in, as the view port changes, some of the hidden markers can then be shown, keeping in mind that there should not be any overlaps. I am not concerned with which marker is shown. Is there any way this can be done in Google maps API or any other plugins? I have looked into the [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier). However, that is not what I am looking for. I am mainly trying to avoid the clutter. OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier does not ensure that. Please note, that I am neither looking at MarkerManager or ViewPort Manager as solutions as neither of them help determine whether or not there is a clutter.

Comment: Keep looking, I'm sure you'll find something. Failing that, you could write some code to do it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to use a marker clusterering library in this situation. These solutions additionnaly give a sense of how many markers are hidden. For example, Google's MarkerClusterer ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering)) changes icon color and label count depending on the number hidden markers.

However, if you really want to keep the same icons, you can overwrite the icons ([`m1, m2, ..., m5.png`](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images)) with yours and hide the labels.